# How to create a number of dictionaries based on a given number in python?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have an HTML page that handles several forms.
When making a post request (i.e. submitting the values of the fields of the different forms) i received in django/python this dictionary:

form-0-Name:Dupont
form-0-Town:Paris
form-1-Name:Macron
form-1-Town:Marseille

From this dictionary, how to create a number of dictionaries based on the number of forms that i receive? 
In this example, i would like to create two dictionaries named (form_0 and form_1) such that form_0:
{Name: Dupont,Town:Paris} and form_1:{Name: Macron, Town:Marseille}.

Comment: don't dynamically create variables, use a container, like a `list`

Comment: Juanpa, after i would like to map these two dictionaries to another dictionary. The other dictionary is {Partie1: Texte1, Partie 2: Texte2} to map with the two others: form_0: {Name: Dupont,Town:Paris, Partie1:yes} and form_1:{Name: Macron, Town:Marseille; Partie2:No}. I think it would be easier to use dictionaries to check if there is any Partie1 and Partie2 in the two dictionaries as i will proceed to a mapping/replacement phase after in  the text1  and text2 with the items of the two dictionaries....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for dict like this :

```
a = {'form-0-Name':'Dupont', 'form-0-Town':'Paris', 'form-1-Name':'Macron','form-1-Town':'Marseille'}
```

you can proceed like this:

```
final = {}
for k,v in a.items():
    key = '_'.join(k.split('-')[:2])
    subkey = k.split('-')[-1]
    final.setdefault(key, {}).update({subkey:v})
```

output :

```
final = {'form_0': {'Name': 'Dupont', 'Town': 'Paris'},
 'form_1': {'Name': 'Macron', 'Town': 'Marseille'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Make an auxiliary function:

```py
def get_form_dicts(form_dict):
    dictionaries = []
    form_strings = list(set([x[0:6] for x in form_dict.keys()]))
    for i in form_strings:
        dictionaries.append({x.split('-')[2]: v for x, v in form_dict.items() if i in x}) 

    return tuple(form_strings)
```

Now, presuming that you know how many forms you are going to get:

```py
# Naming django_dict the dict that is created in your application
form_0, form_1 = get_form_dicts(django_dict)
```

Comment: Sorry i do not know what will be the exact number of forms in advance...